# ::after pseudo uses parent width instead of element width for percentage based positioning

Tags: html, css, pseudo-element

I'm using a psuedo selector for a class on an  (.redTabActive::after) and Im trying to set margin-left of a down carat made with borders to be 50%, but instead of being 50% of the  width, it's using it's parent, a  and appears off the screen for all tabs that are to the left of the middle of the td.

```html
<td>
   <a class="redTab">Tab 1</a>
   <a class="redTab">Tab 2</a>
   <a class="redTab">Tab 3</a>
   <a class="redTab">Tab 4</a>
   <a class="redTab">Tab 5</a>
   <a class="redTab">Tab 6</a>
</td>
```

```css
.redTabActive::after{
    content: '';
    border: 15px solid transparent;
    border-top: 15px solid black;
    margin-left: -50%;
    margin-top: 25px;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    overflow: visible;
    position: absolute;
}
```

I have some javascript that changes the class from redTab to redTabActive when you click on it.  This is where I expected the down carat to position in the middle of the tab, but it appears off the screen for most of the tabs.

Comment: you are looking for transform:translateX(-50%) .. margin uses the parent width, it's by design

Comment: Try adding `position: relative` to `.redTabActive`

Comment: you can also set the parent in position:reltaive to take it into account as the reference

Comment: Just to add to Bali Balo, the absolute position inside table cell is undefined! `<td>` would have to be `display: block;` for example... and to have `postion: relative;` or similar.

Answer (score 0):

one possible example from my comment 'was waiting for kind of feed back )
so position is to start from, then you can choose margin, transform and or coordonates.

```css
.redTab::after {
  content: "";
  border: 15px solid transparent;
  border-top: 15px solid black;
  display: table;/* or any block level display or use top:xx; */
  border-collapse: collapse;/* if table display*/
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -15px;
  position: absolute;
}
a {
  position: relative;/* i'm your father ! */
  display: inline-block;
  border: solid;/* see me */
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <a class="redTab">Tab 1</a>
      <a class="redTab">Tab 2</a>
      <a class="redTab">Tab 3</a>
      <a class="redTab">Tab 4</a>
      <a class="redTab">Tab 5</a>
      <a class="redTab">Tab 6 last one</a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

or

```css
.redTab::after {
  content: "";
  border: 15px solid transparent;
  border-top: 15px solid black;
  top: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -15px;
  position: absolute;
}

a {
  position: relative; /* i'm your father ! */
  display: inline-block;
  border: solid;/* see me */
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <a class="redTab">Tab 1</a>
      <a class="redTab">Tab 2</a>
      <a class="redTab">Tab 3</a>
      <a class="redTab">Tab 4</a>
      <a class="redTab">Tab 5</a>
      <a class="redTab">Tab 6 last one</a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

or

```css
.redTab::after {
  content: "";
  border: 15px solid transparent;
  border-top: 15px solid black;
  top: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translatex(-50%);
  position: absolute;
}

a {
  position: relative;
  /* i'm your father ! */
  display: inline-block;
  border: solid; /* see me */
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <a class="redTab">Tab 1</a>
      <a class="redTab">Tab 2</a>
      <a class="redTab">Tab 3</a>
      <a class="redTab">Tab 4</a>
      <a class="redTab">Tab 5</a>
      <a class="redTab">Tab 6 last one</a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

any of these example starts from `position:relative` set onto the parent which is meant to be the reference for that visual positioning.